# Right way to define pointer to the string array(C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Can I define pointer to a string array like this?

```
std::string* str_arr_p[];
```

Or I need to set the size of the array?

P.S.: Is there any difference between `std::string* str_arr_p[n];` and 
`std::string (*str_arr_p)[n];`

Comment: Recommendation: read about stack and heap memory and about memory allocation. In your case, without any size, how would the computer know which address to give to you? If that address couldn't handle a hundred entries (because after that, the memory is in usage), what should happen? And how should it reserve memory if it has no idea of how much to reserve? Also, in most cases, you should really use a container class like `std::vector` instead.

Comment: And yes, there's a difference. The former declares an array of `n` pointers to `std::string`; the latter declares a pointer to an array of `n` `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I initialize pointer to a string array like this? `std::string* str_arr_p[];`
>   Or I need to set the size of the array?

No you can't. Try it and see that you get compilation error.

> Is there any difference between `std::string* str_arr_p[n];` and
>   `std::string (*str_arr_p)[n];`

Yes there is. The first is an array of *`n` pointers to `std::string`*, the second is *a single pointer to an array of `std::string` of size `n`*.

**Note that both are uninitialized** (if not declared as global or static), i.e. both point or hold arbitrary address(es). The first holds `n` arbitrary addresses that can be initialized separately with a valid address or `nullptr` for each of the `n` pointers in the array. The second is a single address that need to be initialized with an address of an `std::string` array which has the exact size `n`.

Comment: don't you mean "is a pointer to an array of n `std::string` ?"

Comment: sure, fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string* str_arr_p[n];
```

is an array of pointers to `std::string`.
`std::string (*str_arr_p)[n];` here str_arr_p is a pointer to an array of n `std::string`

`std::string* str_arr_p[];` this is a definition, you don't initialize anything.
`std::string* str_arr_p[] = new std::string* [x];` heap allocated or
`std::string* str_arr_p[50];` Stack allocated, this will be destroyed when function ends